# Angular p-dataTable Selection doesn't get updated on model update

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

From my Angular code, I'm calling a synchronous method where there is an asynchronous call to a service(`myService`) which sets the value of a variable(`myVariable`) inside it. This variable `myVariable` in turn is bound with a `p-datatable` object like so:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="someValue" [(selection)]="myVariable" [paginator]="true" #MyTable ...>
```

During the initial page load, the correct values get displayed in the data table. But when there is a change in the data that is returned by the service, it fails to bind to the latest value of the variable without an explicit refresh.

My code snippet:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.getData(par1, par2);
  // other lines of code
  // ........
}

myMethod(){
   this.getData(par1, par2); // this method call is expected to update the value of the variable
   // other lines of code
   // ........
}

getData(p1, p2){
 this.myService.getDataFromServer(p1, p2)
   .subscribe(data => {
       myVariable = data.value;
       // other lines of code
       // ........
    });
}
```

I understand the fact that `myMethod()` is receiving data asynchronously, so maybe the variable is not getting set that's why. I tried to directly subscribe to `myService.getDataFromServer` instead from `myMethod()` but that doesn't work either. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Did you try to use `changeDetector.markForCheck()` after `this.getData(par1, par2)`?

Comment: @Shai I had tried ChangeDetectorRef detectChanges() but with no luck https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the variable(which binds to the datatable) before fetching updated data from the service fixed the issue for me. Code snippet:

```
getData(p1, p2){
 this.myService.getDataFromServer(p1, p2)
   .subscribe(data => {
       myVariable = []; // reset done here
       myVariable = data.value;
       // other lines of code
       // ........
    });
}
```